# How to solve WorkManager is not initialized properly error?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

The project in which currently I am working have been using **targetSDK = 30** & **compileSDK=30**. I upgraded **targetSDK=33*, Now I need to add **android:exported="true or false"** in each activity and I have added. but when I run Nothing screen shows blank screeen and goes into infinite look throwing error

> **Instance creation error : could not create instance for [Factory:'androidx.work.WorkManager']: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.**
> androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.getInstance(WorkManagerImpl.java:156)
> androidx.work.WorkManager.getInstance(WorkManager.java:184)
> org.catrobat.catroid.koin.CatroidKoinHelperKt$componentsModules$1$3.invoke(**CatroidKoinHelper.kt:69**)

Code of **CatroidKoinHelper.kt** is

```
val componentsModules = module(createdAtStart = true, override = false) {
    single {
        Room.databaseBuilder(androidContext(), AppDatabase::class.java, "app_database")
            .addMigrations(DatabaseMigrations.MIGRATION_1_2)
            .build()
    }
    single { CatroidWebServer.getWebService("https://share.catrob.at/api/") }
    factory { WorkManager.getInstance(androidContext()) } //Error was because of this line
    single { ProjectManager(androidContext()) }
    single { NetworkConnectionMonitor(androidContext()) }
    factory { HuaweiApiAvailability.getInstance() }
    factory { GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance() }
    factory { MobileServiceAvailability(get(), get()) }

    single { BackpackListManager.getInstance() }
    single {
        DefaultFeaturedProjectSync(get(), get(), get()) as FeaturedProjectsSync
    }

    single {
        DefaultProjectsCategoriesSync(get(), get(), get()) as ProjectsCategoriesSync
    }
}
```

error was because of this line **factory { WorkManager.getInstance(androidContext()) }**

**Temporary Solution:** I searched in stackoverflow and added following snippet in my **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            android:exported="false">
        </provider>
```

But now when I build my app then shows following errors

> **Work [ id=e78c5f3e-2b24-4556-a702-94278f8eb4c5, tags={ org.catrobat.catroid.sync.ProjectsCategoriesSyncWorker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error**
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
> at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
> at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
> at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:300)
> at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
> at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:678)
> at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:686)
> at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.java:154)
> at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.java:136)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:115)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:94)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:43)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
> at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
> at org.catrobat.catroid.retrofit.ErrorInterceptor.intercept(ErrorInterceptor.kt:33)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
> at org.catrobat.catroid.retrofit.CatroidWebServer$Companion$getWebService$okHttpClient$1.intercept(RetrofitWebServer.kt:71)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
> at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
> at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
> at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204)